# Fluent Nhibernate inheritance throws index out of range exception

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to implement inheritance within fluent nhibernate, yet even the most simple mappings are throwing an exception : Invalid index 1 for this SqlParameterCollection with Count=1.

The mapping that I'm passing is as basic as I can make it, mapping only the Id, the source and the amount but the only parameter that is being passed through to the collection is the amount, not the source (my discriminator) and I'm getting an exception thrown.  I originally wanted my discriminator to be an enum, but since I can't get anything to work, I've made it a string for simplicity.

Though the subclass doesn't currently add any other functionality to the object, others will, and this is the most basic version so I thought it would be easiest...

Reading around this error, the problem is usually due to there being a property mapped in both base and subclass, but as far as I can see, this isn't the case.  Can anyone point out what I've done wrong, as I'm at a bit of a loss.

Classes:

```
public class BasePayment
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Source { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal Amount { get; set; }
}

public class SubPayment : BasePayment
{
}
```

Mappings:

```
public class BasePaymentMap : ClassMap<BasePayment>
{
    public BasePaymentMap()
    {
        DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("Source");
        Table("BasePayments")
        Id(m => m.Id);
        Map(m => m.Source);
        Map(m => m.Amount);
    }
}

public class SubPaymentMap : SubclassMap<SubPayment>
{
    public SubPaymentMap()
    {
        DiscriminatorValue("SourceX");
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 5):

Gaaaaah, figured out the answer shortly after posting.  The discriminator column doesn't need a mapping itself, it is mapped by being designated the discriminator.  Couldn't see the wood for the trees and feeling rather daft now...

Comment: If that column really need to be mapped to a property, then by marking as insert=false, update=false, we can make it.